# Keyboard shortcut to call a function in an Excel addin

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard-shortcuts, excel-addins

We have an excel addin with functions and sub routines. The addin is copied to

C:\Users\<>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns folder.

We are able to assign excel ribbon items to these functions and they work well.

Users would love ability to assign a shortcut to these addin methods. Can this be done?

Comment: How you are planning that users can "assign a shortcut to these addin methods"? Where the shortcuts will be located?

Comment: You mean keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: yes, keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add-in could, in its Workbook_Open event, use [Application.OnKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-onkey-method-excel) so as to associate some of its methods to certain key combinations. Make sure not to intercept key combinations that Excel has a use for already.